# Как обратится к селектору Polygon?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть такой селектор `<polygon class="" points="6.6000000000000005 1 26.400000000000002 1 32 14 26.400000000000002 27 6.6000000000000005 27 1 14" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" fill="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)"></polygon>` у него нет класса. Как к нему можно обратится? Через `fill="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)` возможно?

Comment: `document.querySelector('[fill="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)"]')`  https://jsfiddle.net/hbojgesf/  Только учтите, что даже пробелы в селекторе имеют значения